# Microsoft Bot framework session.endDialog() use

Tags: node.js, botframework

I read the Bot document somewhere people posted if you replace dialog then previous dialog store in stack and stored somewhere.

Now I tried to follow the way to endDialog() then replaceDialog();

```
callRequest.GetWebAPICall(session, urlData, function (body) {
        if(body.statusCode == 200) { 
            if(body.data == undefined) { 
                builder.Prompts.choice(session,Want to Select List?", "Yes|No",{listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});
            } else { 
                session.endDialog();
                session.replaceDialog('/Show List');                
            }
        } else {
            session.send('Something went wrong. You can use the back or top command.');
            session.replaceDialog('/menu');
        }
    });
```

For need to know if I replace below lines

```
session.endDialog();
session.replaceDialog('/Show List');
```

by

```
session.endDialog('/Show List');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `endDialog()` doesn't have the functionality to start a new dialog. You can refer to the function definition interface [`endDialog(message?: TextOrMessageType, ...args: any\[\]): Session;`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L1996L2002).

In your case, `'/Show List'` would be sent to the user as a message.

And there is also a misunderstanding about [`replaceDialog()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L1982).

> Ends the current dialog and starts a new one its place. The parent dialog will not be resumed until the new dialog completes.

If you need to store the previous dialog, you can use [`beginDialog()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L1979)

Comment: Thanks, for clearing my concept for replace and begin dialog